# Larger image in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll, android-volley

In my current project i needed to load a bit large images in ListView with caption and some information.So I start using **Volley** for loading data from server. ListView UI is pretty much the same to android google plus app.By following **Volley** post , i was able to load images correctly and display them was perfectly fine. But the problem is when i **scroll down** list view , it impact on my scrolling .
I uploaded [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZc_XF0HXkU) , to let you know my prob a bit more . 
**Note** -It is working fine with small thumbnail

Here is my **ViewHolder** and **getView** method in Adapter

```
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    TextView desc;
    NetworkImageView thumbnail;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_list_item, null);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();


    holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_title);
    holder.desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_description);
    holder.thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_photo_thumbnail);
    v.setTag(holder);

    Photo photo = this.getItem(position);

    holder.title.setText(photo.getPhoto_title());
    holder.desc.setText(photo.getPhoto_desc());

    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    }

    holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(photo.getPhoto_url(), mImageLoader);       
    return v;
}
```

**My LruCache**

```
public class MBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

    public MBitmapCache(){
        this(getDefaultCacheSize());
    }

    public MBitmapCache(int maxSize) {
        super(maxSize);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static int getDefaultCacheSize(){
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String key, Bitmap value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        put(key, value);
    }

}
```

**My Volley Controller**

```
public class VolleyController extends Application{

    private static final String TAG = VolleyController.class.getSimpleName();
    private static VolleyController mClassInstace;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        mClassInstace = this;
    }

    public static synchronized VolleyController getInstance(){
        return mClassInstace;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader =  new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new MBitmapCache());
        }
        return mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        req.setTag( TextUtils.isEmpty(tag)? TAG : tag );
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void CancelPendingRequests(String tag){
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tag)) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you use `ViewHolder` pattern and image caching library?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I used Volley and LruCache. Not the one you suggest . I am gonna have a look.

Comment: I am wondering which is not happening on scrolling up and only occur in scrolling down

Comment: Thank you , @BlazeTama . I tried with ViewHolder but it doesn't seem fixed

Comment: @user20978 Try UniversalImageLoader or Picasso

Comment: Have you tried lazy loading the images asynchronously in the background [LazyList Example](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: hi @Wildroid , currently i am using Volley . Volley also did pretty much of background processing and image caching out of the box .

Comment: Please check if your list has match_parent in its height. I had this problem before, if you have the View Holder pattern and you are reusing the views correctly, then check that in the listview. If not match_parent, then wrap_content. Sorry, can't recall exactly.

Comment: @user20978 - I realize that - I was suggesting not to use Volley and load images in other thread and cancel thread if image is no longer needed. Load image using BitmapFactory.Options and inSampleSize. If you prefer to use a library and Volley is not capable, you should try Picasso - it can handle large images without lag in scrolling - [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thank @tiago7 , I tried changing but it still exist .

Comment: Just a moment, let me look at the project. I am sure that I had this problem with the scrambled images before. And I used UniversalImageLoader.

Comment: Thanks @Wildroid ,I will have a look at Picasso .

Comment: I checked now. It was changing the list height to match_parent. Are you sure this didn't do anything? If not, then please try adding these two methods like this to the adapter. This was my first solution to this problem.

Override

public int getViewTypeCount() {

return getCount();
}

Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

return position;
}

Comment: Hi @tiago7 , I added and double checked but it is not working. Surprisingly , I changed Volley NetworkImageView's width from **mathc_parent** to **wrap_content** , it worked . Thank you for your suggestion , it helped me. But I want to display full width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : your doing about ViewHolder is wrong, you performed `setTag` but you never perform `getTag` when **convertView** not null.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_title);
        holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_description);
        holder.thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo_thumbnail);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

that would save the performance as much as possible, you can checking the [google tutorios](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) for details.

Second : it appeared your ImageLoader doesn't use memory cache, please post the code that how you initializing the Volley `RequestQueue` and `ImageLoader`, make sure your ImageLoader would use BitmapCache.

Comment: what size is for `getDefaultCacheSize` returned?

Comment: after i had change the ViewHolder implementation correctly as u mentioned , my scrolling was working fine . But i don't know whether this images are being cached or not .

Comment: Thank you ,Now i got my listview scrolling perfectly fine for both direction . Can u pls let me know how to check whether my images are being cached or not ?

Comment: in my experience, i'd use 2mb memory as bitmap cache, 24576b = 24kb is not capable to caching your large bitmaps. you can debug or log the `MBitmapCache.getBitmap()` method to checking if this method return a  viable bitmap instance to checking whether the request use memory cache or not.

Comment: good news , they are cached and also successfully retrieved . thanks